# How to show a screen when app crash anywhere

Tags: android

how can i show a default screen about "some error occurred" when my app going crash anywhere . 
like sometimes its happened in facebook and other apps , whenever app going out of control of try catch block then automatically a screen open showing Error. 
please help me , if here in android have any callback if app crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use library called `CustomActivityOnCrash`. With it, you can specify your default `Activity` when the app crashes. So, to set it up do as follows:

1) Add  `compile 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.2.0'` to your `app` level `build.gradle`.

At this point if you run your app and encounter a crash then a default error `Activity` from the library will be shown.

However, if you'd like to show your own error `Activity` you need to do 2 additional steps.

2) Define your error `Activity` in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="CustomErrorActivity"
    android:label="@string/error_title"
    android:process=":error_activity" />
```

3) Extend your `Application` class as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();    

    CaocConfig.Builder.create()
        .trackActivities(true) //default: false
        .errorActivity(CustomErrorActivity.class)//
        .apply();
}
```

For more information about the library please go [here](https://github.com/Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash)

Answer (score 1):

To show a custom activity on app crash you can use the library [CustomActivityOnCrash](https://github.com/Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash)

To use this library just follow this steps:

1.Add the dependencies to your build.gradle file

```
implementation 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.2.0'
```

2. Add a custom activity to show the crash.

```
<activity
android:name="CustomErrorActivity"
android:label="@string/error_title"
android:process=":error_activity" />
```

3. Add these lines of code to your error acitivity that extends Application

```
CaocConfig.Builder.create()
    .backgroundMode(CaocConfig.BACKGROUND_MODE_SILENT) //default: CaocConfig.BACKGROUND_MODE_SHOW_CUSTOM
    .enabled(false) //default: true
    .showErrorDetails(false) //default: true
    .showRestartButton(false) //default: true
    .logErrorOnRestart(false) //default: true
    .trackActivities(true) //default: false
    .minTimeBetweenCrashesMs(2000) //default: 3000
    .errorDrawable(R.drawable.ic_custom_drawable) //default: bug image
    .restartActivity(YourCustomActivity.class) //default: null (your app's launch activity)
    .errorActivity(YourCustomErrorActivity.class) //default: null (default error activity)
    .eventListener(new YourCustomEventListener()) //default: null
    .apply();
```

For more information and advance customization of the library [click here](https://github.com/Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CustomActivityOnCrash library

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();

CaocConfig.Builder.create()
    .backgroundMode(CaocConfig.BACKGROUND_MODE_SILENT) //default: CaocConfig.BACKGROUND_MODE_SHOW_CUSTOM
    .enabled(false) //default: true
    .showErrorDetails(false) //default: true
    .showRestartButton(false) //default: true
    .logErrorOnRestart(false) //default: true
    .trackActivities(true) //default: false
    .minTimeBetweenCrashesMs(2000) //default: 3000
    .errorDrawable(R.drawable.ic_custom_drawable) //default: bug image
    .restartActivity(YourCustomActivity.class) //default: null (your app's launch activity)
    .errorActivity(YourCustomErrorActivity.class) //default: null (default error activity)
    .eventListener(new YourCustomEventListener()) //default: null
    .apply();
}
```